# Extract JS object from another file into variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have a file `object.js` which contains a javascript object:

```js
{
    key: value,
    anotherKey: { a: b }
}
```

Inside another file, say `reader.js`, I would like to read from `object.js` and put that **javascript object** into a **variable** which would act as a normal js object

```js
const fs = require("fs");

let content = fs.readFileSync("object.js");
console.log(content); // looks good

let object = { ...content };
console.log(object); // bad and wrong...

// expected: { key: value, anotherKey: { a: b } }
```

Any ideas how to parse the js object from `object.js` and put it into a valid object variable?

`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content))` didn't help.

Comment: Why would you call `JSON.stringify()` first? `content` is just a string at this point, so all you need is to call `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @MTCoster, the point was that the `object.js` file is NOT valid JSON and it shouldn't be - it's a JavaScript object, hence it's not parsable with `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` or a combination of both. I just tried to provide more information about what I tried to help others help me faster:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is a JS file, you could consider them as a module and export them

Comment: Thanks! I solved it by adding `module.exports = { ... }` at the beginning of the `object.js` file and then using `let object = eval(content)` in `reader.js`, which works perfectly (eval is safe in my case since it's a startup script)!

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFileSync` will return the content of the file as a string. You should parse that string into a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse(content)`. However, your file doesn't seem to be valid JSON - you must wrap your keys with `"` and any string values with `"` as well.

Comment: Thanks, the point was that the `object.js` file is not JSON, but a JavaScript object:)